# counting elements in a list based on another list

Tags: r

I have two lists looking like this:

```
mylist <- list(a=c(1:5), 
               b = c(5:12), 
               c = c(2:8))

list.id <- list(a=2, b=8, c=5)
```

I want to count the number of elements in `mylist` that are higher than the corresponding element in `list.id` and divide the result for the `length` of element in mylist. I have written this function.

```
perm.fun <- perm.fun2 = function(x,y){length(which(x[[i]] < y[[i]]))/length(x[[i]])}
```

However, when I do: `lapply(mylist, perm.fun, list.id)` I do not obtain the expected result.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `lapply`, you would need to loop on the indices (`1`, `2`, `3`) so they can be used to extract the elements from both `mylist` and `list.id`:

```
perm.fun <- function(i, x, y) mean(x[[i]] > y[[i]])
lapply(seq_along(mylist), perm.fun, mylist, list.id)
```

But `mapply` is a much better tool for that task. From the doc:

> mapply applies FUN to the first elements of each ... argument, the second elements, the third elements, and so on.

So your code can just be:

```
mapply(function(x, y) mean(x > y), mylist, list.id)
#         a         b         c 
# 0.6000000 0.5000000 0.4285714
```